# can you print text to the bitmap display in mips?

Tags: assembly, bitmap, mips, mars-simulator

so for a final project in a class, we can make some sort of project in mips. I wanted to make a snake game using the bitmap display. it's a game to help kids learn their times tables and it randomly generates an equation from the 12 times tables and generates a correct answer and an incorrect answer. The code for generating the equation works but here it is just for reference:

```
#equation stuff
m1: .word   1 #multiplicand
m2: .word   1 #multiplier
ans:    .word   1 #correct answer
w1: .word   1 #an incorrect answer
w2: .word   1 #an incorrect answer
w3: .word   1 #an incorrect answer



    .text 
randomEqGenerator:
    li $a1, 13 #upper bound for random number is 13. Multiplicands and multipliers range from 0-12
    li $v0, 42
    syscall
    sw $a0, m1

    li $a1, 13 #upper bound for random number is 13. Multiplicands and multipliers range from 0-12
    li $v0, 42
    syscall #get the multiplier
    sw $a0, m2

    #get correct answer
    lw $t1, m1
    lw $t2, m2
    mult $t1, $t2
    mflo $t3
    sw $t3, ans

    #generate incorrect answers
    sub $t4, $t3, $t2
    sw $t4, w1

    sub $t4, $t3, $t1
    sw $t4, w2

    add $t4, $t3, $t1
    sw $t4, w3
```

so the main question is is it possible to simply print text on a bitmap display? all of the cases that i've seen do this make words using the pixels but I can't do that because the equation is randomly generated. so is it possible to print text to the bitmap display/ is there some sort of workaround to this?

thanks!

Comment: Is it possible? Yes, sure, you are daily using computers which draw letters on bitmap-like displays. Is it easy? Not as easy, as calling single syscall. I don't completely understand, where the random nature of equation blocks you from printing it with pixels. You need some kind of "font" data for each digit, and split your values into separate digits (same as million of questions here on SO asking how to convert number values into string, because many platforms don't have system service to print number (MARS is sort of extra easy to new coders, helping with that). Etc...

Comment: that's most likely what will have to be done